# MarketTarget: SQL DE Queries: Need to exclude certain duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I started with  creating an event query that would pull everything from 30 day from today. Exclude any duplicate IDs and a few other rules. As for now Im able to pull the events for the next 30 days but I can seem to find online how to exclude duplicates.

```
SELECT event_date, event_id, venue_id 
FROM event 
 [event_id] not LIKE '%%' AND
where event_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY event_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it'll work for your requirements, [**distinct**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx) will filter the duplicates.  No need for the **group by**.

You can check for empty/null with the [**isnull()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function and do your date math using the [**dateadd()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function.

```
SELECT distinct
  cast(event_date as date) as event_date /* strip time from date */
  , event_id
  , venue_id 
FROM event 
where 
 isnull([event_id],'') != '' /* event_id is not empty/null */
 and event_date >= dateadd(d,-30, cast(event_date as date)) /* within the last 30 days */
```